# Where is appcenter applications location?

Tags: appcenter

I have recently installed some new apps from appcenter. For example "Go Fot It!". I don't know how to run this app without searching it in appcenter. Firstly, is there something like "my apps" or something else to run installed apps? Secondly, I want to run some of them from the terminal. Then how can I know the names of the executable files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such applications should add a .desktop file so that you can open them from the Applications menu.

The application "Go For It!" does seem to appear in my Applications menu. It added a `/usr/share/applications/com.github.jmoerman.go-for-it.desktop` file.

Looking at that item with the AppEditor (an easy way to inspect / edit .desktop files) it shows that it opens `com.github.jmoerman.go-for-it`. Which makes sense since that naming scheme is a requirement for adding applications to the AppCenter. See: https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started#the-desktop-file

Running `whereis com.github.jmoerman.go-for-it` tells me it's located in `/usr/bin/`.

There isn't really one applications folder in linux, but when you try to execute an application it looks for that application in the folders listed in the PATH environment variable. See: `echo $PATH` (separated by `:`'s).

I don't know whether the applications you install from the AppCenter will always be installed in the same folder.